# Differential equations, theoretical question.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$ L(x)=x^{(n)}+a_1(t)x^{(n-1)}+\cdots +a_{n-1}(t)x'+a_n(t)x=b(t);\qquad a_1(t),a_2(t),\ldots\in C$$
$$U_j(\varphi)= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(M_{jk} \varphi^{k}(\alpha)-N_{jk} \varphi^{k}(\beta))= \gamma_j\quad \text{or} \quad U(\varphi)= \gamma$$ $$L(x)=0 \\ U(x)=0 \tag{1}$$

$(1)$ has to be solved. This is how the answer starts off, if anyone can pinpoint the detail, step that I am not seeing feel free to notify me.

Let $\varphi_{1}(t), \varphi_2(t),\ldots,\varphi_n(t)$ be the fundamental set of answers, the Vronski matrix : $W(t)=W(\varphi_1(t),\varphi_2(t),\ldots,\varphi_n(t))$ and the algebraic complement of the element $._{ni},\ \ $ $W_{ni}(t)$. We have the given formula: $$\varphi(t)= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \gamma_i \varphi_i(t)+ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\varphi_i(t) \int_{\alpha}^{t}\frac{W_{ni}(s)b(s)}{W(s)}ds $$ from here we have: $$\varphi(t)= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \gamma_i \varphi_i(t)+ \int_{\alpha}^{t}K^{*}(t,s)b(s)ds \tag{${*}{*}{*}{*}$}$$
where:
$$K^{*}(t,s)=\frac{1}{W(s)} \begin{vmatrix}
\varphi_1(s) & \varphi_2(s)& \cdots& \varphi_n(s)\\
\varphi_1'(s)& \varphi_2'(s)& \cdots & \varphi'_n(s)\\ \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ 
\varphi^{(n-2)}_1(s)& \varphi^{(n-2)}_2(s)& \cdots & \varphi^{(n-2)}_n(s)\\ 
\varphi_1(s) & \varphi_2(s)& \cdots & \varphi_n(s)
\end{vmatrix}$$

Also: $$\gamma_i = \int_{\alpha }^{\beta}u_i(s)b(s)ds, i=1...n$$
How is the sum lost in (****), and so on..?

Comment: Interesting question, I would like to see an answer come out of this one..

Comment: Likewise, believe me..

Comment: What are your $M_{jk}$ and $N_{jk}$?

Comment: they are constants